# Illustration of Von Neumann's Minimax theorem in games?

Tags: machine-learning, game-theory

The Von Neumann's [Minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem) gives the conditions that make the [max-min inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality) an equality.

I understand the max-min inequality, basically $\min(\max(f))\ge \max(\min(f))$.

The Von Neumann's theorem states that, for the inequality to become an equality $f(.,y)$ should always be convex for given $y$ and $f(x,.)$ should always be concave for given $x$, which also makes sense.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-EewaiFhF0&list=PLAwxTw4SYaPnidDwo9e2c7ixIsu_pdSNp&index=61) says that for a zero-sum perfect information game, the Von Neumann's theorem always holds, so that minimax always equal to maximin, which I did not quite follow.

**Questions**
Why zero-sum perfect information games satisfy the conditions of Von Neumann's theorem?
If we relax the rules to be non-zero-sum or non-perfect information, how would the conditions change?

---

<sup>This question was originally posted on the [AI site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1446/185) and closed as off-topic.</sup>